# Precision loss when multiplying Decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal

When trying to multiply two decimal objects in python I am experiencing precision loss. How can I fix this?

```
    u = Decimal("1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769480731766797379907324784621070388503875343276415727350138462309122970249248360558507372126441214970999358314132")
   y = Decimal(10**100)
   z = u*y
   str(int(z))
=> '14142135623730950488016887240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: I guess you are getting precision loss because you cast your `u*y` product to `int`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decimal is not arbitrary precision like `int` is, but rather has a fixed but changeable number of decimals of precision. This is 28 by default, which happens to be where your number cuts off at the moment.

You can change this by doing `decimal.getcontext().prec=128` or to whatever precision you need. For more information, I refer you to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem"

You could change that by calling `decimal.getcontext().prec = 256`(or any other value fitting your purpose)